# How does this loop capitalize each word in a string

Tags: python

The purpose of the below code is to capitalize the first letter of each word.

Can someone explain the below code to me?

```
s="hello world"    
for x in s[:].split():
   s = s.replace(x, x.capitalize())
print(s)
```

What's the value of `x` in this loop?

Comment: `x` is each word in your string.

Comment: [How to debug small programs.](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)
|
[What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953)
You can find out the answer by simply `print(x)` in the loop, or stepping through your code with a debugger.

Comment: There's no need to write `s[:]`. Strings are immutable, so yuo can't modify the string in place, so there's no need to make a copy.

Answer (score 2):

This way is highly inefficient and incorrect.

1. You'll read and replace the whole string for each word. So if you have a 100 words sentence, you will evaluate 10,000 words. The complexity increases quadratically
2. The solution is actually providing incorrect results as it replaces inner strings as well

```
s = "abc a def e c ghi"

for x in s[:].split():
   s = s.replace(x, x.capitalize())
print(s)
```

output: `AbC A DEf E C Ghi`

One correct way to do this is for example to split the string and capitalize each word individually:

```
S = ' '.join(w.capitalize() for w in s.split(' '))
```

Comment: How does this answer the question "what's the value of x in this loop?"

Comment: @Barmar I agree it doesn't, but using `replace` for such a purpose is a nonsense. It will loop over the whole string for each word, increasing the complexity quadratically.

Comment: So? He asked for an explanation of the algorithm, not an improvement.

Comment: @Barmar and there were already nice comment addressing this aspect. I think it would be to bad not to provide a "correct" way to do this. Then it's only my opinion...

Comment: You could repharse the answer, then to say that `x` is each word, but talk about how `.replace` will find all instances of that same word, and replace them **all at once** , as compared to your answer here, which looks at each word individually

Comment: @OneCricketeer OP's algorithm is also plain wrong (see my update). I am sorry if you don't like it, but I feel it's some kind of "duty" to report this and provide a valid approach. This is also part of learning a language. My 2 cents…

Comment: I personally didn't downvote, but like Barmar said, it didn't really answer the question that was being asked

Comment: Thanks for the fix ;)

Comment: I don't think "you will evaluate 10,000 words" is correct, is it? 10K characters (plus spaces), yes, not "words" out of 100 replace calls over 100 words (and there could be duplicate words)

Comment: It's an approximation, if you have duplicates however it will still read the string for each duplicate.

Comment: Actually it will read the string once per word, so for 100 words, 100 times the string and each of the 100 words, so 10000 words (and many more characters as words are likely more than one character)

Comment: thank you guys for making me understand the code. Also i see you guys making improvement for the code and explaining why my code is inefficient ,I appreciate the correction also.

Answer (score 1):

Running this code piece:

```
for x in s[:].split():
    print(x)
```

We see the output:

```
hello
world
```

So, 'x' would be the individual words in a sentence. The next line in the original code:

```
s = s.replace(x, x.capitalize())
```

simply replaces the the words individually in the original string with the capitalized versions.

Comment: thank you guys for making me understand the code. Also i see you guys making improvement for the code and explaining why my code is inefficient ,I appreciate the correction also.